# add facebook wall into own site

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-wall

How can I mirror the content from company facebook page Wall post to my company page??

Example i have a company website www.ABC.com/news.html that I want to retrieve the content from www.facebook.com/ABC(this our the company facebook page). I just want the wall content but not the rest of it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Watch this video for the answer:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT06SP7YV5o&feature=plcp
It will shows you how to add html to a fan page and all related
stuffs to facebook timeline for business.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use the [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Answer (score 0):

use it for create a wall like facebook in your personal website :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/